# Get return function value in promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I use javascrip and promise.

I search a way to get return value where xxxx is wrote, is there a way to get it

```
jQuery.ajax({

    success: function(data, status, jqXHR){

        const promise = requestUpdated(data.poviderId);

        promise.then(function(data_tt) {
            return updateAircrafts(data.sspId, data.id); //result 
        }).then(function() {
            //xxxx
            transForm.deserialize("#form", data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
        });

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {

    }
});
```

Comment: It's passed as an argument to the callback to `.then`: like `.then(function(xxxx) {`. Same as `data_tt` in the previous one.

Comment: You'll want to use `jQuer.ajax(…).then(function(data) { … })`. Don't ever pass `success` and `error` callbacks when working with promises!

Comment: Don't mix callback and promises (It makes error handler a nightmare).  If you're going to use promises, then use the promise that `jQuery.ajax()` returns instead of the success callback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the argument in order to obtain it. This parameter will be the data that's being returned in the `then` statement beforehand:

```
jQuery.ajax({

    success: function(data, status, jqXHR){

        const promise = requestUpdated(data.poviderId);

        promise.then(function(data_tt) {
            return updateAircrafts(data.sspId, data.id); //result 
        }).then(function(result) {
            // console.log(result);
            transForm.deserialize("#form", data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
        });

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {

    }
});
```